# Drools compare two objects in decision table

Tags: drools

I have the following code in DRL file

```
rule "MyExample"
when
    $eentity : ExampleEntity()
    $sentity : SecondEntity( secondField == $eentity.getMainField())
then
    System.out.println(true);
```

end

This is works but I need to convert it to spreadsheet table. I tried so much variants but no one works. How can I write this rule in decision table?

Comment: Of course if it is possible to define this rule in decision table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single condition column:

```
CONDITION
ExampleEntity($mf: mainField) SecondEntity
secondField == $mf /*param*/
Combine Ex with Sec on equal field values
x
```

The `/*param*/` and the `x` is a hack to get the condition being generated for the row.

Comment: Thanks but I got twice "true" in console. Why?

Comment: And how can I write the following rule with your example:
CONDITION
ExampleEntity($mf: mainField, $sc: secondaryField) SecondEntity
getSecondaryExampleEntity(ExampleEntity)
How can I write the last row?

Comment: How often you'll see an output from this rule depends on the facts in WorkingMemory.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Start a new question and show the rule you want to have, not spreadsheet entries - I don't know what you want to match.