# Drools Decision Table object comparison gives inverted results

Tags: java, drools, business-rules

I have been struggling with a problem considering Drools and this is kind of my last resort.

Assume I have a list of 3 people: [1, 2, 3]. Think of this list as a list of ID values for these people.
Now, I want to evaluate all unique pairs of these people in the following order:

1. Person 1 against Person 2;
2. Person 1 against Person 3;
3. Person 2 against Person 3.

My spreadsheet's RuleTable looks like this:

[image: RuleTable PSBR]

It makes use of a trick mentioned in this comment: [Drools compare two objects in decision table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28276208/5347955).

The Person class had been correctly imported, the three people have been inserted into the session and every Person object has a `getId()` method.

However, running `fireAllRules()` on the session gives me the following output:

1. Person 1 vs Person 1
2. Person 2 vs Person 1
3. Person 2 vs Person 2
4. Person 3 vs Person 1
5. Person 3 vs Person 2
6. Person 3 vs Person 3

You might notice that that's the complement of the set of results I would have liked.

**Please note!** After a wild guess, it turned out that changing the condition `id > $id1` to`id < $id1` solves this problem, but then the logic appears to not match in my head.

The rule I'm trying to mimic looks something as follows:

```
rule "same-company"
    when
        $p1 : Person($id1 : id)
        $p2 : Person($id2 : id, id > $id1)
    then
        System.out.println($p1.getId() + " " + $p2.getId());
end
```

This rule works fine and as expected on its own in a .drl file!

So my questions are:

1. **Is this what the spreadsheets are supposed to do?**
2. **If not, what could I be doing wrong here?**

I also have some more complex variables inside Person objects that I'd like to apply logic to (maps of strings for each person that I'd like to compare values of), to which the same thing happens; Drools spreadsheets seem to let a rule pass when the conditions I set have NOT been met. Targeting the opposite is possible, and works, but to me it doesn't seem like that's the way this should work.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Edit 1:**
The generated DRL using [Drools - Using “from” in decision table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34649384/5347955) returns the following result:

```
package org.ps.dtable;
//generated from Decision Table
import org.ps.orm.Person;
// rule values at C12, header at C7
rule "PSBR_12"
    when
        $p1:Person ($id1: id) $p2:Person($id2:id, id > $id1 /*param*/ == "X")
    then
        System.out.println($p1 + " vs " + $p2);
end
```

The Excel spreadsheet looks like this:
[image: Spreadsheet]

**Edit 2:**
The $ in `/*$param*/` was missing, and caused weird evaluation. Lesson learned; never forget about the money.

Comment: Regarding the "inverted results", I'd like to see the generated DRL  (see link in my answer) in combination with the Excel cell contents.

Comment: I've added these things to the question! Thanks for your time so far.

Comment: Thanks for adding the original code and result - this opened my eyes for seeing what is missing. See the PPS in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how operators `<` or `>` could ever produce `1 vs 1`, but that's probably not the most important issue.

More importantly, I can't reproduce this problem using version 5.5.

Older versions may have handled this particular situation differently. Then it was important to realize that the spreadsheet compiler squeezes the constraint (what you have in row 4) into the *parentheses* of row 3 (unless the rows are formed according to a different pattern, with == added automagically). You may try to add a pair of parentheses after the second Person

```
CONDITION
$p1:Person($id1:id) $p2:Person()
$id2:id > $id1 /*$param*/
pairs ordered by ascending id
```

If this doesn't work, you'll have to upgrade.

PS: For debugging, printing the generated DRL is essential. See my answer in [Drools - Using "from" in decision table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642884/drools-using-from-in-decision-table)

PPS: Careful reading always helps. I overlooked that you had `/* param */` **without the dollar sign** in your question, and so the generated rule had `== "X"` appended to the constraint. Strange at it seems, this compiles, and evaluates in a very weird way, which I can't figure out right away. Probably any string that is not equal to "true" is considered to be equal to "false", which would then work like a negation and produce the result you couldn't figure out. No wonder. (Very likely, the MVEL evaluation is at the bottom of this, which has produced other baffling effects.)

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding it, it didn't work. I'm using Maven imports to access Drools and the related imports I've done are `kie-api 6.3.0-Final`, `kie-ci 6.3.0.Final`, `drools-decisiontables 6.3.0.Final`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought they're the latest versions. I'm a beginner to the whole Maven thing, which might be the issue.

Comment: Quick note, you might want to check the original answer, it doesn't have the $ either. I guess it was logical, but I oversaw it, so others might too. :(

Comment: My *answer* had the $ all the time, but, yes, your question didn't have it, and I didn't see it, as I confessed in my answer. - I wrote an email to the Drools usage list, let's see what the Droolers say.

Comment: Aah I meant the answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28276208/5347955), sorry. This answer was all I've ever wanted it to be. ^.^" Thanks again, it helped me a lot!